# Performing SSL Server Verification in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, verification

I currently work on code that connects to a server to retrieve a configuration file. It is required that this happens in a secure way via HTTPS. I discovered that the current implementation does not really meet this requirement:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.configserver.com/...");

if (ReloadGlobals.IgnoreSSLErrors) // always true
    httpWebRequest.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.None;

if (m_ReloadConfig.DontCheckSSLCert) // always true
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnCheckSSLCert);

httpWebesponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

The Remote Callback is implemented in this way:

```
private static bool OnCheckSSLCert(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

I dont really know much about HTTPS but even I can see that this doesn't make much sense and looks like a workaround. So I need to find a way to implement this in a proper way.

I'm thankful for every piece of advice.

Edit:
Part of the requirements:

> Once an address and URL for the configuration server is determined,   the peer MUST form an HTTPS connection to that IP address.  If an optional URL for the configuration server was provided, the   certificate MUST match the domain name from the URL as described in   [RFC2818]; otherwise the certificate MUST match the overlay name as   described in [RFC2818].  If the HTTPS certificates passes the name   matching, the node MUST fetch a new copy of the configuration file.

Comment: If your application only needs to communicate with a single server, you could hardcode the certificate fingerprint.

Comment: That's unfortunately not the case. There could be a lot of different configuration servers in the future.

Comment: I'd expect the default handler (when you don't subscribe to `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` at all) to be sensible. Probably using the same logic internet explorer uses. You could try default settings and then attack with SSLsniff.